# Send calendar item properties from Acces form to Outlook agenda

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

My script in Access-vba works (I can send from an Access form a calendar item to Outlook). But now I want to send some poperties (such as subject and location of the appointment) to the agenda in Outlook and then I get an error (see image attached). For subject I want to use some text from my current form (Me.Monitor_account) but that does not work. See the image attached. If I use: .Subject = "test" then it works. But I dont see the difference between the two.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

.Subject = (Me![MonitorAccount]) 'worked!